# RabbitMQ guaranteed delivery - Is republisher service the right solution

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging

We use RabbitMQ as a broker where we separate OLTP web applications that process transaction data from other concerns such as reporting applications. In this particular ecosystem, the reporting data must be as up to date as possible so there is no tolerance for messages to just go permanently missing.

However messages can go missing for various reasons, and even with the inbuilt rabbitmq publisher confirms and acknowledgements enabled we may still have some messages go missing in the case of edge case scenarios e.g. network failures.

So we came up with a solution - a republisher service.

The republisher service works as follows:

- Kicks off every 30 minutes via a schedule
- For appropriate time window, gets event counts from source (WebServiceA) data store, gets event counts from destination (ReportingService) data store, checks if they match up. If they match - exit
- As counts did not match, gets the last 2 hours worth of event data from the source applications dababase (WebServiceA)
- Republishes every message to rabbitmq broker
- The subscribing application (ReportingService) is idempotent i.e. it can handle receiving the same message many times

[image]

The solution we have works, it does not 100% guarentee delivery but with the safety net of the republisher service we have yet to see messages to not get to their destination.

The question I have is are we doing this the wrong way or are we reinventing the wheel? Is there anyone out there that has similar requirements and did you go about guarenteeing delivery in a similar way?

We do know that this approach is poor from an architectural perspective as the republisher needs direct access to both source and destination database. (shared database). It also means that any time we need to add reporting for new source services, we have to write republication code also.

Comment: Yes, you are reinventing the wheel. I suggest upgrading to RabbitMQ 3.8.0 when it is available and using quorum queues (along with publisher confirms, persistent messages, etc). They will address the already very rare edge cases where messages could be lost. To be honest I'm surprised you ever ran into message loss scenarios - they usually depend on using an old, buggy Erlang, old RabbitMQ version, or not choosing the right partition handling strategy.